# Artificial Intelligence music maker

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Do you know the name of a tool to do some tones from a set of examples, I recently heard it created a great classical song like Bach's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been at least one neural network attempt where the input for the network is music samples, and the output is also music samples. Therefore if the network is trained on Bach, it will output Bach-sounding music. You may be more specifically referring to the [Harmonisation of Bach chorales](http://www.ofai.at/~soren.madsen/daimi/harmreport.pdf) paper:

> This project is an attempt to produce intelligent machine harmonisation of
>   chorales. The goal is to harmonise melodies in the style of J.S.Bach; we wish to
>   nd tendencies and perhaps rules that Bach may have followed consciously or
>   unconsciously.
>   We have chosen a GA approach to construct the new harmonisations. We
>   discuss the use of rule-based evaluation and proceed to make experiments that
>   are based on neural net tness evaluation after training on a set of Bach chorales

Comment: Do you know if there is a tool for music for download?, is it free?

Comment: @darkcminor. Sorry, but anything I've read or heard of has been completely a research effort and I'm unaware of any downloadable software. You could try contacting the authors of the paper to see if they can help.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cope

http://artsites.ucsc.edu/faculty/cope/